# asignar variable

Tags: javascript, servlets

Como puedo pasar el valor de String usuario a Usuario user ?

```
public Usuario valida(String usuario) {
        System.out.println("Ingresa a metodo Valida BnUsuario: "+usuario);
        Usuario user = null;
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        if ("usuario@gmail.com".equals(usuario)){
```

}
else{}

clase usuario

public class Usuario {

```
private BigInteger id_usuario;
private String usuario;
private String clave;
private String nombre;
private String nombre_s;
private String apellido;
private String apellido_m;
private String telefono;
private String correo;
private Date creacion;
private String ip;
private Usuario_estado estado;
private String perfil;
private String perfil_s;
private String sucursal;    
private String sucursal_s;
private Filial filial;
//id_sucursal;
//id_perfil;

public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(BigInteger id_usuario) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
}

public BigInteger getId_usuario() {
    return id_usuario;
}

public void setId_usuario(BigInteger id_usuario) {
    this.id_usuario = id_usuario;
}

public String getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public String getClave() {
    return clave;
}

public void setClave(String clave) {
    this.clave = clave;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getNombre_s() {
    return nombre_s;
}

public void setNombre_s(String nombre_s) {
    this.nombre_s = nombre_s;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getApellido_m() {
    return apellido_m;
}

public void setApellido_m(String apellido_m) {
    this.apellido_m = apellido_m;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public void setCorreo(String correo) {
    this.correo = correo;
}

public Date getCreacion() {
    return creacion;
}

public void setCreacion(Date creacion) {
    this.creacion = creacion;
}

public String getIp() {
    return ip;
}

public void setIp(String ip) {
    this.ip = ip;
}

public Usuario_estado getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Usuario_estado estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}
```

Comment: no comprendo muy bien cual son las variables que quieres asignar porfavor aclara mejor tu duda para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora que has aclarado la clase Usuario, tu código podría quedar así:

```
public Usuario valida(String usuario) {
        System.out.println("Ingresa a metodo Valida BnUsuario: "+usuario);
        Usuario user = null;
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        user = new Usuario();
        if ("usuario@gmail.com".equals(usuario)){
            user.setCorreo(usuario);
        } else{
        }
```

Comment: esta es la clase usuario :

Comment: amigo no me funciono , me arroja error